# How to parse multiple objects using JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
let string = "{
    "path": "transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy - Copy.xml",
    "fullPath": "D:\\fileuploader\\TEST_2\\transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy - Copy.xml",
    "basename": "transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy - Copy.xml",
    "stats": {
        "dev": 3356173649,
        "mode": 33206,
        "nlink": 1,
        "uid": 0,
        "gid": 0,
        "rdev": 0,
        "ino": 1125899908018589,
        "size": 604,
        "atimeMs": 1560493097203.9585,
        "mtimeMs": 1510127196336.229,
        "ctimeMs": 1560493097204.9585,
        "birthtimeMs": 1560493097203.9585,
        "atime": "2019-06-14T06:18:17.204Z",
        "mtime": "2017-11-08T07:46:36.336Z",
        "ctime": "2019-06-14T06:18:17.205Z",
        "birthtime": "2019-06-14T06:18:17.204Z"
    }
}
{
    "path": "transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy.xml",
    "fullPath": "D:\\fileuploader\\TEST_2\\transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy.xml",
    "basename": "transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy.xml",
    "stats": {
        "dev": 3356173649,
        "mode": 33206,
        "nlink": 1,
        "uid": 0,
        "gid": 0,
        "rdev": 0,
        "ino": 1688849861395786,
        "size": 604,
        "atimeMs": 1560493067976.2869,
        "mtimeMs": 1510127196336.229,
        "ctimeMs": 1560493067977.2869,
        "birthtimeMs": 1560493067976.2869,
        "atime": "2019-06-14T06:17:47.976Z",
        "mtime": "2017-11-08T07:46:36.336Z",
        "ctime": "2019-06-14T06:17:47.977Z",
        "birthtime": "2019-06-14T06:17:47.976Z"
    }
}"

console.log(JSON.parse(string))
```

My string is looks like this, i have to convert into array of objects, i tried using **JSON.parse()** nut throws error unexpected "{" at line like that.

**NOTE/UPDATE :** I piped object stream (converted to string type using Tranform) and piped to process.stdout in my child process.

in parent i get above string on child.stdout.on("data")

If i have only one object means no error, but for this.
How to convert this into array of object ?.

***UPDATE: In Child.js***

```
var jsonStream = through2.obj(function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
let details = JSON.stringify(chunk, null, 4) + ',' + '\n'
this.push(details)
callback()
})

files.pipe(jsonStream).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: Can you post the Json you are trying to parse at least ?

Comment: @QuentinRoger i added !

Comment: What you've called string isn't a string; it doesn't need parsing, it's already an object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is string from stdout, for sample i posted like this.

Comment: That's still not syntactically valid JavaScript. Also why do you *need* to parse multiple objects, why aren't they in an array?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i updated my question, i am get this from my child process stdout.

Comment: @Ram then why not have the child process produce valid JSON?

Comment: @VLAZ i updated what i done in child process, so how to process valid JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the site 'https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer' to know if your json string is right.
It's wrong because you can use array or a object and you string isn't no one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

The following will parse.

You cannot have a string with \n in it and it is not valid JSON even if you do not. You need to wrap in `[]`, have comma between the objects and escape the backslashes.

You need `\\\\` to escape the backslashes in this case

```js
let string = `[{
        "path": "transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy - Copy.xml",
        "fullPath": "D:\\\\fileuploader\\\\TEST_2\\\\transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy - Copy.xml",
        "basename": "transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy - Copy.xml",
        "stats": {
            "dev": 3356173649,
            "mode": 33206,
            "nlink": 1,
            "uid": 0,
            "gid": 0,
            "rdev": 0,
            "ino": 1125899908018589,
            "size": 604,
            "atimeMs": 1560493097203.9585,
            "mtimeMs": 1510127196336.229,
            "ctimeMs": 1560493097204.9585,
            "birthtimeMs": 1560493097203.9585,
            "atime": "2019-06-14T06:18:17.204Z",
            "mtime": "2017-11-08T07:46:36.336Z",
            "ctime": "2019-06-14T06:18:17.205Z",
            "birthtime": "2019-06-14T06:18:17.204Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "path": "transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy.xml",
        "fullPath": "D:\\\\fileuploader\\\\TEST_2\\\\transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy.xml",
        "basename": "transition_26_1_0 - Copy (2) - Copy - Copy.xml",
        "stats": {
            "dev": 3356173649,
            "mode": 33206,
            "nlink": 1,
            "uid": 0,
            "gid": 0,
            "rdev": 0,
            "ino": 1688849861395786,
            "size": 604,
            "atimeMs": 1560493067976.2869,
            "mtimeMs": 1510127196336.229,
            "ctimeMs": 1560493067977.2869,
            "birthtimeMs": 1560493067976.2869,
            "atime": "2019-06-14T06:17:47.976Z",
            "mtime": "2017-11-08T07:46:36.336Z",
            "ctime": "2019-06-14T06:17:47.977Z",
            "birthtime": "2019-06-14T06:17:47.976Z"
        }
    }]`

console.log(JSON.parse(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

Write on this way

```
JSON.parse('
  [
    {
      "key": "value", 
      "key": "value"
    },
    {
      "key": "value"
    }
  ]
')

OR

JSON.parse('
  {
    "object": 
    {
      "key": "value", 
      "key": "value"
    },
    "object": 
    {
      "key": "value"
    }
  }
')
```